# How to display all of a varbinary(max) column in CR 2008?

Tags: sql-server, varbinary

I am using Crystal Reports 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

I am having an issue with displaying a `varbinary(max)` column from SQL Server in CR. The column is all text. When I try displaying it in CR, I do not get all of the text. It limits what is shown.

I would appreciate any help on resolving this. Thanks.

Ken

Comment: When it's **TEXT**, then **WHY ON EARTH** is it `VARBINARY(MAX)` (and not `VARCHAR(MAX)` as it should better be!)

Answer (score 0):

You can find columns of certain type by querying sys.columns however it sounds like if text is getting cut off you may need to enable CLOB/BLOB support or increase the supported amount of what is interacting with the DB.

As an aside, why not store text as varchar(max) or text field?

Comment: How can I enable CLOB/BLOB in CR?

Comment: That I don't know as I don't have CR.  But I have seen these symptoms  in other applications (i.e. Coldfusion Application Server).